# Dart StageXL activate mouse event on overlapping sprites

Tags: dart, mouseevent, sprite, stagexl

Is it possible to have a mouse event be called for two sprites overlapping?  I have attempted to use `getObjectsUnderPoint` however it does not seem to be working.

```
class Line extends Sprite
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int type;
    var tempLine = new Shape();
    bool isClicked = false;

    Line(int xPos, int yPos, int type)
    {
        this.x = xPos;
        this.y = yPos;
        this.type = type;

        if(type == 1)
        {
            graphics.beginPath();
            graphics.moveTo(x, y);
            graphics.lineTo(x+300, y);
            graphics.closePath();
            graphics.strokeColor(Color.LightGray,19);
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, react);
            tempLine.graphics.beginPath();
            tempLine.moveTo(x,y);
            tempLine.graphics.lineTo(x+300,y);
            tempLine.graphics.closePath();
        }
        else if(type == 2)
        {
            graphics.beginPath();
            graphics.moveTo(x, y);
            graphics.lineTo(x, y+300);
            graphics.closePath();
            graphics.strokeColor(Color.LightGray,19);
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, react);
            tempLine.graphics.beginPath();
            tempLine.moveTo(x,y);
            tempLine.graphics.lineTo(x,y+300);
            tempLine.graphics.closePath();
        }
        addChild(tempLine);
    }

    react(MouseEvent event)
    {
        Point tempPoint = new Point(event.localX, event.localY);
        graphics.strokeColor(Color.Black,19);
        isClicked = true;
        var subShape = getObjectsUnderPoint(tempPoint);
        for(Shape i in subShape)
        {
            i.parent.userData.isClicked = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I have two `Line` objects overlapping and when one is clicked I want the boolean for both objects to be `true`. I have read that the `getObjectsUnderPoint` does not return a `Sprite`, could this be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MouseEvents are only dispatched to the top most display object that extends the InteractiveObject class (which is true for all DisplayObjectContainers and Sprites). So only one display object can receive the MouseEvent.CLICK event. You are right that the getObjectsUnderPoint does only return the children of DisplayObjectContainers but there is an open issue on the GitHub repository (https://github.com/bp74/StageXL/issues/209) talking about this. One of the next versions of StageXL (greater than version 0.13) may change this behavior.

Comment: Maybe i should have explained it in more detail: You don't get DisplayObjectContainers (Sprites) with the getObjectsUnderPoint method, therefore you don't get the Sprite where you draw the line with the graphics property. But you can use the Shape class which has a graphics property too to draw the line and add this instance as a child to the Sprite instance. The method getObjectsUnderPoint should then return the Shape instance.

Comment: I updated the code to address your comment, however now nothing is rendering.  Can I have the `Shape` be a child of the `Sprite` instance? It seems that the rendering is stopped when I attempt to add an instance of `Shape` to `Sprite`.

Comment: Yes, a Shape is a DisplayObject and every DisplayObject can be added to the Sprite class since a Sprite is a DisplayObjectContainer.